# Is there a way to mock the return for type(), without replacing with isinstance()?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am trying to unit test a block of code, and I'm running into issues with mocking the object's type to grab the right function from a dictionary.

For example:

```
my_func_dict = {
    Foo: foo_func,
    Bar: bar_func
    FooBar: foobar_func
}

def generic_type_func(my_obj):
    my_func = my_func_dict[type(my_obj)]
    my_func()
```

With this code, I can swap between functions with a key lookup, and it's pretty efficient.

When I try to mock my_obj like this, I get a KeyError:

```
mock_obj = Mock(spec=Foo)
generic_type_func(mock_obj)

# OUTPUT:
# KeyError: <class 'unittest.mock.Mock'>
```

Because it's a mock type. Although, when I check isinstance(), it returns true:

```
is_instance_Foo = isinstance(mock_obj, Foo)
print(is_instance_foo)
# Output: 
# True
```

Is there any way to retain the type() check, and using the dictionary lookup via a key, while still maintaining the ability to mock the input and return_type? Or perhaps a different pattern where I can retain the performance of a dictionary, but use isinstance() instead so I can mock the parameter? Looping over a list to check the type against every possible value is not preferred.

Comment: I would consider getting rid of `generic_type_func` altogether. `Foo.func = staticmethod(foo_func)`, then `my_obj.func()` should work.

Comment: @chepner this is what I ended up doing. I wanted to keep the functionality on the parent, instead, because it modifies properties on the parent. Maybe I could call back to the parent from the parameter's function later. This works for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to unit test this by moving the function to the parameter itself, and implicitly calling the function from the parent. I wanted to avoid this, because now the function manipulates the parent implicitly instead of explicitly from the parent itself. It looks like this now:

```
def generic_type_func(self, my_obj):
    my_obj.my_func(self)
```

The function then modifies self as needed, but implicitly instead of an explicit function on the parent class.

This:

```
def my_func(self, parent):
    self.foo_prop = parent
```

Rather than:

```
def my_foo_func(self, foo):
    foo.foo_prop = self
```

This works fine with a mock, and I can mock that function easily. I've just hidden some of the functionality, and edit properties on the parent implicitly instead of explicitly from within the class I'm working in. Maybe this is preferable anyways, and it looks cleaner with less code on the parent class. Every instance must have my_func this way, which is enforced via an abstract base class.